# Jsoup замена html элемента

Tags: java, jsoup

Добрый день,
Как с помощью jsoup заменить html код элемента?
К примеру div на `<!--div-->`
Входной код`<body><div>Текст <div> Текст 2</div></div></body>`
На `<body><div>Текст <!--div--></div></body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно как-то так:

```
String html = "<body><div>Текст <div> Текст 2</div></div><div>Текст33 <div> Текст 44</div></div></body>";
```

берем элементы

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements els = document.select("div > div:contains(Текст 2)");
for (Element el : els) {
    el.replaceWith(new TextNode("<!--div-->", ""));
}

System.out.println(document);
```

либо

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements els = document.select("div > div");
for (Element el : els) {
    if (el.text().contains("Текст 2"))
        el.replaceWith(new TextNode("<!--div-->", ""));
}

System.out.println(document);
```